# How to switch multiple signal lines with a single mechanical switch

Tags: switches

I want to switch an FTDI interface with a single mechanical switch towards two different endpoints. The FTDI interface has six lines, four two-way digital lines, plus power and ground.

My mechanical switch should be a single SPST or SPDT switch.

With relays, the answer would look like the schematics below. I would need six SPDT relays for that.

I would like to have a smaller solution, with a minimum of components and complexity.
Voltage and currents of my circuit are low, about 3.3V and 10mA.

[image: schematics]

Comment: like a cross port switch, as in any line can go to any other line? Or like a relay that you just want the electrical connect removed....  Also, they'll want to get specs voltage, current, etc...

Comment: Like a relay, each line has to be separate. I will add the information to the question.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are these signals or power? Analog or digital signals?

Comment: All lines are digital signals.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, you don't want to use relays? Solid state relays are fast, low power and quiet.

Comment: I thought a solution with six relays would be too big for my small breadboard. I have not thought of solid state relays though. Can you recommend a cheap solid state relay for low power usage? Would I use six of these, or is there an IC which contains multiple relays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the switch to control analog switches. The switch then just needs to be SPST with a pullup resistor. This will be the control signal to the analog switches. One switch line can easily drive many CMOS inputs, so fanning out to six won't be a problem.

Analog switches are sometimes called "bilateral switch" because, unlike "digital muxes", they work just as well in both directions -- much like a relay.
Sometimes I use an analog switch to connect the output of one chip to either one of two "input" lines (with pull-up or pull-down resistors to set the "other" line to the appropriate state), much like a digital demultiplexer.
Sometimes I use an analog switch to connect the input of one chip to either one of two "output" lines (no resistors are needed for this case), much like a digital mux.
Sometimes I use an analog switch to connect a bidirectional line like the I2C data line.

Analog switches act much like relays, except
(a) they can't handle much current -- some handle 25 mA, others can handle only 10 mA.
(b) they can handle only a limited voltage range -- some handle 0 to +15 V, others handle only 0 to +5 V.
(c) they are lower cost, can switch far more rapidly and more often, and require much less power than relays.

(This is a minor tweak of the answer from Olin Lathrop).

Some parts I would consider:

- 74HC4066 quad SPST bilateral analog switch
- 4053 triple SPDT analog switch
- 74HC4353 triple SPDT analog switch
- 4052 dual SP4P analog switch
- 74HC4852 dual SP4P analog switch
- 14551 quad SPDT analog switch

You might be able to do this with two chips, and perhaps some pull-up or pull-down resistors.

Comment: I didn't know analog switches. Exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the switch to control digital muxes.  The switch then just needs to be SPST with a pullup resistor.  This will be the control signal to the muxes.  One switch line can easily drive many CMOS inputs, so fanning out to six won't be a problem.

Comment: Can I also do it with a couple of simple transistors? These I have on my hand.

Comment: Could you recommend a mux or range of muxes for the OP?

Comment: How would the mux solution work? As far as I understand, a mux would have one output line. Wouldn't I need six muxes then?

Comment: @henning: Yes, you would need six 2:1 muxes.  However, you can often find multiple muxes with a common control input in the same chip.  For example, the 74x158 is four 2:1 muxes in a 16 pin chip.  You would need 1 1/2 of those.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a couple of transistors (or, more likely, FETs), but we would need more info: what is connected to the inputs and outputs? (But the Muxes that Olin proposed are essentially a bunch of such FETs in a convenient package...)

Comment: It is an FTDI interface. Connected to inputs is a USB-BUB, to the outputs two Arduino RBBB's. I want to switch the USB-BUB between the two RBBBs without reconnecting the cable. I will probably try the ICs Olin proposed to make things convenient. It would have been interesting for me though if I could do it with simple transistors. I guess this would *only* be interesting if it could be done with one transistor per line :-) Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: @henning: I don't know what a USB-BUB or a RBBB is, but this won't work if you are trying to switch the USB lines.  Those are not strictly digital and are not one-way.

Comment: Thanks Olin for the clarification. The lines are not USB lines, but more similiar to RS232 serial lines I think. But still, they are for two-way communication, so you are right: The muxes solution won't work for my case.

Comment: @Henning Please make a schematic of what you want to do, with the specific devices, and update your question.